# Reading multiple excel sheets with different worksheet names

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I would like to know how I can read multiple excel worksheet with different worksheet name in c# and with the used of oledb.

I have this existing way to read multiple sheets (but with fixed worksheet name):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
var excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path); 
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = excelConnectionString;

var i = 1;
while (i <= 4)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet" + i + "$]";
    ds.Clear();
    OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
    data.Fill(ds);

    // other stuff
    i = i + 1;
}
```

This one works. But I'm now in different situation wherein the worksheets names are not fixed, example: Sheet1 is Dog, Sheet2 is Cat Sheet3 is Bird.

Now my concern is how I can loop on those worksheet names with the use of my existing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from VB.net but not sure how well it translates, returns a list of strings containing all sheet names:

```
OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})
```

**[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)**

Once you have a list of sheet names you can do a simple `For Each` loop to iterate.

**Edit:**

This should work in C#

Add function

```
static DataTable GetSchemaTable(string connectionString)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new 
               OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
            OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
            new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
        return schemaTable;
    }
}
```

Your code would change to:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
var excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path); 
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = excelConnectionString;

DataTable sheets = GetSchemaTable(excelConnectionString);

foreach (dataRow r in sheets.rows)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + r.Item(0).ToString + "]";
    ds.Clear();
    OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
    data.Fill(ds);

}
```

Just be sure to do something with `ds` after each iteration.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the idea. Now i will have to look for c# version of that :)

Comment: You are definitely correct. I already made the solution. and it looks just the same to your solution. Thanks! Cheers! :)

Comment: anyway, I found a solution from here as well http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8096/C-Retrieve-Excel-Workbook-Sheet-Names

Answer (score 0):

i use code below , it worked on my different sheets in one excel file.

```csharp
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ratesFilePath, false))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
    Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
    foreach (Sheet sheet in sheets)
    {
        if (sheet.Name == "Sheet Name")
        {
            Worksheet worksheet = ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id)).Worksheet;
            SheetData sheetData = (SheetData)worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            foreach (Row row in sheetData)
            {

                if ((row.FirstChild as Cell).CellReference.ToString().Contains("A") && (row.FirstChild as Cell).CellValue != null && row.RowIndex != 1)
                {
                    RateInformation RateInformationElement = new RateInformation();
                    foreach (Cell c in row)
                    {
                        string cellValue = null;
                        if ((c.DataType != null) && (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
                        {
                            int id = -1;
                            if (Int32.TryParse(c.InnerText, out id))
                            {
                                SharedStringItem item = GetSharedStringItemById(workbookPart, id);
                                if (item.Text != null)
                                {
                                    //code to take the string value
                                    cellValue = item.Text.Text;
                                }
                                else if (item.InnerText != null)
                                {
                                    if (Convert.ToDouble(item.InnerText).ToString() != null)
                                    {
                                        cellValue = Convert.ToDouble(item.InnerText).ToString();
                                    }
                                    else 
                                    { 
                                        cellValue = item.InnerText;
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (item.InnerXml != null)
                                {
                                    cellValue = item.InnerXml;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cellValue = c.InnerText;
                        }
                        if (c.CellReference.ToString().Contains("A"))
                        {
                            RateInformationElement.Unit = cellValue;
                        }
                        else if (c.CellReference.ToString().Contains("B"))
                        {
                            Decimal.TryParse(cellValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimal result);
                            RateInformationElement.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(result);
                        }
                    }
                    rateInformations.Add(RateInformationElement);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```