# import data from multiple excel files into datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am getting list of excel files within specific directory as below

```
    public void GetFilesList()
    {
        ListFiles = Directory.GetFiles(DefaultDirectory, "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string FilePath in ListFiles)
        {
            ImportExcel(FilePath);
        }
    }
```

then I am trying to add rows from each file within that directory into my `datagridview` as below

```
    public void ImportExcel(string FilePath)
    {
        string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";";
        OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);

        OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", Conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            DA.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            //Calculate record counts
            L_Total_Rows.Text = "count: " + dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString("n0");
            Conn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

my problem is that it import rows form one excel file only 
it wont get into else condition it only get into the if condition then stops importing

another one question anyway to NOT use the sheet name at query [Sheet1$]? I don't know if it is possible the index of sheets ?

can I start importing the excel file form specific row like fourth row of excel file ?

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0` is only true for the first file...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592424/reading-multiple-excel-sheets-with-different-worksheet-names shows you how to iterate through sheets...

Comment: I am reading this code, and I cannot figure out from what you wrote what it is that you would like it to do. There is no logical progression that I could interpret.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia which is true at first file it will populate it into `datagridview`  and since  at second iteration  there is records in `datagridview` i want to add to it the rest of rows from other files .. so I mad the else condition to add rows ... am I right ?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia I do not want to  iterate through sheets i want to iterate through files in directory

Comment: When you get to the “else” portion of the “if” statement in the “ImportExcel” method… the `DataTable` `dt` will ALWAYS be empty… it is NEVER filled, hence no rows will be added. In addition, in the `foreach` loop, adding a row to the grid, then setting the grids `DataSource` won’t work as you expect. You may want to clarify what you are wanting to do.

Comment: @JohnG thanks you I have post the answer for my problem thank you bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was solved by moving `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` to the beginning of the class because each time I am calling `ImportExcel(FilePath)` method it will build new `datatable` so it will delete all old data and create new `datatable` and changed my method to below

```
    public void ImportExcel(string FilePath)
    {
        string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";";

                    OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
        OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", Conn);

        DA.Fill(dt);
        DGV_Data.DataSource = dt;
        //Calculate record counts
        L_Rows_Count.Text = "Count: " + (DGV_Data.Rows.Count - 1).ToString("n0");
        Conn.Close();

    }
```

now there is a small problem still annoying me which is it will insert an empty row at `datagriview` between each imported excel file

Comment: You should make your changes (add a row) to the `DataTable` not the `DatagridView`.

Comment: @JohnG I have removed all .. update my answer with new method

Answer (score 2):

How about you combine your result sets into one data table first:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using(OleDbDataAdapter a1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", Conn))
a1.Fill(dt);

using(OleDbDataAdapter a2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", Conn))
a2.Fill(dt);
```